# Unable to drop Primary Key from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have primary key for a table. I checked constraints by using below query.

```
 SELECT name
 FROM sys.key_constraints
 WHERE [type] = 'PK'
   AND [parent_object_id] = Object_id('<TableName>');
```

Output of above query: **PK_dbo.TableName** (only 1 constraint of entire table)

I am trying to drop above constraint by using below query.

```
 ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT PK_dbo.TableName;
```

I tried as like below but same error.

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName DROP CONSTRAINT PK_dbo.TableName;
```

Query execution failed with error message :

> Failed to execute query. Error: Incorrect syntax near '.'

What is wrong in above query?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the **dot** `.` in your constraint name.

If it is there, then type the constraint name inside square brackets, otherwise make sure you are giving the correct name

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TableName];
```

**Note**: It is not recommended to use characters like dot, blank space etc in object names. Instead, use underscores like `PK_dbo_TableName`

Comment: Thanks . square brackets around constraint name fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `.`  in your primary key name. It can be avoided by using `[ ]` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TableName];
```